# I am working with Visual Studio 2008. Actually there is References folder missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am working with Visual Studio 2008. Actually there is References folder missing in its solution explorer. When I create a New web Application it has References folder but when I add new .aspx file it also adds .aspx.designer.cs file with it and its does not show master page option in add dialogue. but in the old web application it shows the master page option where master page file is already added. whats the difference between these two solutions. And how can I make it correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right-click on project node. Select "Add new item" -> "Web Content Form". You will be prompted to select the appropriate master page.

Comment: its like this

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/734fe6ed5f.jpg 

thats what I said that its not asking for any master page

Comment: Correct. If you want to be prompted for a master page, just select the Web Content Form instead of the Web Form. Then it will ask you :-)